Linearly independence of parallel vector fields at a point implies globally linearly independence.
Here is one of my homework question:
Let $(M^m,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold, $\{X_1,\dots,X_r\} \ (r\leqslant m)$ be parallel vector fields. Show that
(i) If for some $p\in M$, $\{X_1|_p,\dots, X_r|_p\}$ are linearly independent, show that $\{X_1,\dots,X_r\}$ are linearly independent everywhere.
I have no idea how to show this. The only thing I know is that linearly independence at a point always implies locally linearly independence, but how to use the parallel condition to show it globally?
Any Hints or References are appreciated. THANKS!

Parallel-transport is an isomorphism. So linear independence at one point implies that for all points which are able to be connected along a curve (which on a connected manifold is all of them).

Maybe it is more intuitive to think contrapositively. If the vectors are linearly dependent at some point, then the linear dependence persists under parallel transport.
